# ImportError: No module named os | trying to run .exe programm

Tags: python, sys, wine, python-os, ubuntu-20.10

I'm using Ubuntu 20.10 and I am relatively new to Linux so I would like to kindly ask you to tell me if there is any info needed.

I am trying to install Ableton Live 10 in Ubuntu but I get this when I try to `wine program_name.exe`

```
wine Ableton\ Live\ 10\ Suite.exe 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "ssl\__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    import os, sys
ImportError: No module named os
wine: Unhandled exception 0x80000003 in thread 2b at address 000000007BCDDFCC (thread 002b), starting debugger...
0x000000007bcddfcc DbgBreakPoint in ntdll: int  $3
Modules:
Module  Address                 Debug info  Name (171 modules)
ELF         7a800000-        7aa0e000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
  \-PE          7a850000-        7aa0e000   \               opengl32
ELF         7b000000-        7b0e2000   Dwarf           kernelbase<elf>
  \-PE          7b010000-        7b0e2000   \               kernelbase
```

.... and at the end

```
 System information:
   Wine build: wine-5.0 (Ubuntu 5.0-3ubuntu1)
    Platform: x86_64
    Version: Windows 7
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 5.8.0-43-generic
```

I think that I need to have to install a os and sys file but I have no idea what these are except that there maybe python files. I had the same error with a not existing ssl file which I downloaded and it worked but now I am stuck here.

I've tried to look for some solution online but there are either not the right error or the problem has to do with writing code instead of installing and so I don't know to solve it by myself. I hope you guys can help me out..

Can anyone suggest a solution? Thanks :D

Comment: When you turn a Python program into an exe, it bundles up the original script, plus a Python interpreter, plus all of the modules that script needs (like os and sys) into a zip file, which is part of the exe.  Usually, when executed, it unzips that file and runs the Python interpreter, and it finds everything.  Apparently, that isn't working in wine.  Lookat https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/7d9x2i/is_anyone_using_ableton_on_linux/